# Show that ($|F (A)| = |A|$ for every measurable $A \subseteq U$) $\iff$ ($|$det $dF (x)| = 1$ ∀x ∈ U$)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, diffeomorphism

Let $U \subseteq $ $R^n$ be an open set, and let $F: U \rightarrow R^n$ be a diffeomorphism.

Show that:

($|F (A)| = |A|$ for every measurable $A \subseteq U$) $\iff$ ($|$det $dF (x)| = 1$ $∀x \in U$).

Comment: What are your thoughts? What relevant facts do you know? Can you prove one of the directions?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I know that $R^n$ and U are open. And since $A \in U$ is measurable, we have $|F(A)| = \int_A |$det$ dF|$. But I don't know how to use this.

Comment: Well, this formula should immediately settle the $\impliedby$ direction, right? For the other direction, use this formula and take a limit as $A$ shrinks to $x$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis thank you. But could you please show me the $\Rightarrow$ direction?